# Just Installed Ubuntu on Laptop

Tags: drivers

So I am running Ubuntu on my clevo w110er (i7-3630Q, gtx 650m, Samsung ssd). My question is do I need to install drivers to get the full potential out of my hardware when I'm on Ubuntu? I also have bluetooth on this laptop but Ubuntu doesn’t see the any bluetooth devices. How can I fix this?

Comment: For bluetooth try `sudo apt-get install blueman`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a basic Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) on my laptop, and I didn't need to install any drivers..

For bluetooth try `rfkill list all`.
check if the Bluetooth is *Soft Block* or *Hard Block*.
If it is *Soft Block*, enter `rfkill unblock bluetooth`.
If the latter, it means that there is a switch somwhere in your laptop for turning the Bluetooth on. Search for it and turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, from experience, that if you're going to be doing any graphic arts or video editing and you've only got the base Ubuntu, not a flavor, you might need to install a driver for watching videos/listening to mp3's. Not sure if it's any different if you've got a different flavour. You might also need to install video codecs, not sure which ones depending on what you've already got. Look around and play around, see if there's anything that gives you an error.

Edit: That's if using ubuntu 16.04. What version are you using?